# Powershell replace only exact match string

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I want to replace the exact word using replace but I can't seem to figure out.

```
$value1 = "I brought tea for my team"

$newValue = "coffee"
$token = "tea"

$value1 -replace $token, $newValue
```

Actual Result:

> I brought coffee for my coffeem

Expected result:

> I brought coffee for my team

Fix:

```
$value1 = "I brought tea for my team"

$newValue = "coffee"
$token = "tea"

$value1 -replace "\b$token\b", $newValue
```

Comment: does the search string always appear in the middle of the string, separated by spaces? (e.g. not ```I brought tea```, ```tea was what I brought```, ```I brought "tea" for my team```)

Comment: Try `-replace "\b$token\b", $newvalue`

Comment: Thank you Theo! works great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Theo is correct. You can use regular expressions and the Word Boundary `\b` to wrap your search term to only match whole words.

```
$value1 = "I brought tea for my team"

$newValue = "coffee"
$token = "tea"

$value1 -replace "\b$token\b", $newValue
```

Comment: I don't get it, why use variables at all, why not just use `$value1 -replace "\btea\b", "coffee"` ? By mixing constructs with variables `\b$token\b` you pretend to know what a _$token_ is...

Comment: @sln, $token is defined in the original post. The question is also tagged PowerShell. It makes sense to anyone who knows PowerShell. The original post was also using variables for matching and replacement. Why not have the answer follow the original idea? It shows the flexibility of the language.

Comment: @AdminOfThings - What ? Language flexibility ? if `$value1 = "I brought -'tea' for my team"` and   if `$newValue = "coffee"` and `$token = "-'tea'"` or even  `$token = "tea"` won't match. I thought it was a regex question ?

Comment: "I want to replace the exact word using replace" + "Expected result" should answer your question, @sin =)

Answer (score 2):

Just like Theo mentioned on the comments...

```
λ  $value1 = "I brought tea for my team"
λ  $newValue = "coffee"
λ  $token = "tea"
λ  $value1 -replace $token, $newValue
I brought coffee for my coffeem

λ  $value1 -replace "\b$token\b", $newValue
I brought coffee for my team
```

You need to set boundaries. Even if you're not a city.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
$token = " tea "
$newValue = " coffee "
```

Comment: You can, but you'd be altering the variables values, instead of using replace to solve the problem, which seems to be the point here